# theorem of the alternatives and infeasibility

Tags: linear-algebra

Trying to prove a simple thing using Motzkin (or Farkas) theorem. 
Given a set in two dimensions defined as $x: Ax \leq b$, we assume that $\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & - 1 \\
     A
 \end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ does not have solutions (i.e. the set is such that $x_1 > x_2$, and also $\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 1 \\
     A
 \end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{bmatrix}$ does not have solutions, i.e. the set is such that $x_1 < x_2$.  Obviously, from these two we must conclude that $Ax \leq b$ does not have solutions.

If I write these conditions using Farkas lemma I get

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & A^T \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} y = 0, \begin{bmatrix}0 & b^T \end{bmatrix} y < 0$ for some $y \geq 0, y \neq 0$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & A^T \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} z = 0, \begin{bmatrix}0 & b^T \end{bmatrix} z < 0$ for some $z \geq 0, z \neq 0$.

What I need to show for infeasibility of $Ax \leq b$ is that exists $w$ such that 
$ A^T w = 0, b^T w < 0$ with $w \geq 0, w \neq 0$.

This is where I got a bit stuck. 
If I add up two conditions I have for $y$ and $z$, I get

$\begin{bmatrix} y_1 - z_1 \\ z_1 - y_1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & A^T \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} (y+z) = 0, \begin{bmatrix}0 & b^T \end{bmatrix} (y+z) < 0$ and $(y+z) \geq 0, (y+z) \neq 0$ also holds. I seem to be one step away, but how to show that $\begin{bmatrix} y_1 - z_1 \\ z_1 - y_1 \end{bmatrix} = 0$ ???

Comment: Turned out to be straightforward :)

Comment: What holds for y, holds also for ky, where $ky_1 = z_1$. Assuming neither $y_1$ nor $z_1$ are 0, otherwise the result is straightforward.  After this add up as above, and done.